# How can I properly use bootstrap on my site?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, rows, responsive

I just started using bootstrap, and I am creating a website using it. But I have been told that I am not using it correctly. Can someone show me how I would properly use bootstrap? Thanks for any help.

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1C213D;
    background-image: url("background.png");
}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 5000px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, .4);
}

.nav-pills li a{
   /* 0.5s is the amount of time it take to change colors */
   transition: .3s background ease-in-out;
}

ul li{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Play";
    display: block;
    color: lightsteelblue;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

p{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 265px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
}

.project1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 275px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 800px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.project2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 275px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.project3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 275px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.project4{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 275px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 800px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(56, 179, 206, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 54px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

i{
    margin-top: 675px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>  
<body>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
                    <img src="logo.png">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
            </ul>
      </div>
        <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
             <p>This is the home page.</p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need to use these two lines the way you did:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
```

These lines are better written like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<div class="col-xs-7">
```

But even this is technically a potential problem because on xtra small screens you want to generally (not always) have the items extend all the way across the screen.

So a better thing to do is to write the media query classes starting at the small or medium screen size and let every screen size underneath use the default 100% width.  That would look like so:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="col-md-7">
```

Furthermore, this is not necessarily incorrect but you forgot to add the Bootstrap Javascript to the document.  NOTE: You will also need to include jQuery BEFORE the Bootstrap Javascript so that it works.  Bootstrap JS is dependent on jQuery.

Lastly, in your css you are styling generic elements.  What you want to do is copy and paste the component CSS with all of the default bootstrap classes and then add another custom class to the items you want to edit to look different.

So, this line:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
```

Should look like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked my-awesome-custom-element" role="tablist">
```

And then you can write CSS for `my-awesome-custom-element` that will ONLY target your custom element without messing with underlying Bootstrap CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the bootstrap js (or the required jQuery) files. See this link:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-get-started.php

Also, this is redundant:

```
class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"
class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7"
```

They can be consolidated into:

```
class="col-md-4"
class="col-md-7"
```

If you are using different widths for different screen sizes, then this would be appropriate:

```
class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-8"
class="col-md-4 col-lg-7 col-xs-6 col-sm-5"
```

Finally, if you are using the bootstrap grid system, then **usually** you want to make your column width add up to 12:

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div><div class="col-md-5"></div><div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

I would recommend reading up on the bootstrap grid system:  http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

add this in the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```